# Converting EBCDIC to ASCII file format- SerDe for hive. How to overcome issue of delimiter in EBCDIC file

Tags: hadoop, hive, ascii, ebcdic, hive-serde

There is nothing like /n in ebcdic. There is no support for new line in ebcdic. 
How should I convert that like.  There is no delimiter in ebcdic. So while converting this file. How shall I know that new line has come? 
Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a new-line character (x'15'). Normal ZOS files do not use the New-Line character. ZOS is built around Fixed-Width, VB, VSAM etc files.

Options include:

1. If it is a Text file (unlikely) convert the file to ascii when it is transferred off the mainframe.
2. Convert the File to Text on the Mainframe and convert when transferring off the mainframe.
3. Use a commercial package. Sync-Sort has **DMX-h**, there is also **Datameer**
4. If you have Cobol copybook, look at these open source packages:

   - https://wiki.cask.co/display/CE/Plugin+for+COBOL+Copybook+Reader+-+Fixed+Length
   - https://index.pocketcluster.io/tmalaska-copybookinputformat.html
   - https://github.com/ianbuss/CopybookHadoop
   - https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltocsv/
5. [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/)  could be used with a Cobol Copybook, Plain Java Code or a Xml file description
   6.

Comment: Thank you soo much..  But I also wanted to know how to handle dynamic arrays

Comment: By dynamic arrays do you mean `variable sized Cobol Arrays` (Cobol occurs depending) ???

Answer (score 0):

A new line in EBCDIC is usually formed from the carriage-return character (hex 0D) and line-feed (hex 25).  In ASCII carriage-return is also hex 0D but the line-feed character needs to be converted to hex 0A.
Hope this helps.